# Radio Buttons Selectable While Moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider a scenario where your form utilizes custom radio buttons. These radio buttons have the following CSS applied to them - which creates the illusion of selectable images - no js at all.

```
#ImageSelector label > input{ /* HIDE RADIO */
    display:none;

}
#ImageSelector label > input + img{ /* IMAGE STYLES */
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
#ImageSelector label > input + img:hover{ /* (CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    border:2px solid #00a8ff;
}

#ImageSelector label > input:checked + img{ /* (CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    border:2px solid #0184c8;
}
```

The problem occurs when the user attempts to click on an image and the cursor is still moving - the item won't become clicked. This is expected behavior of typical radio buttons. Is there a quick way to make the radio buttons more 'sensitive' to the click action or clickable while the mouse cursor is moving?

**UPDATE:** https://jsfiddle.net/7aLbgqr6/

Also, the solution can definitely include jQuery - but it MUST as simple as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Onmousedown event?

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you looking to keep this without JS? maybe try using `:focus` or `:active`?

Answer (score 1):

Modified your fiddle to attach `mousedown` events to the buttons using jQuery. Additionally, I converted the images to use `background-image` instead so that the ghost image does not appear when the mouse cursor moves. Just a slight optional improvement.

https://jsfiddle.net/kpLLr03y/6/

Comment: Note the updated fiddle url. However, utilizing the mousedown event override might be the solution. I'll continue testing.

Comment: Great. Would you mind accepting this answer if it has helped you?

Comment: I will once extensive testing has confirmed this as the solution.